# Extracting attribute value using lxml

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I am using lxml library to get the attribute value from a HTML page.

For example :

```
<span class="you-save">Rs. 5000</span>
```

I am getting the correct result (5000) using below

```
print doc.xpath('//span[@class="you-save"]//text()')
```

I want to get the attribute value, for example

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="4999.00">
```

I want to extract "4999.00". I am unable to figure out this.

I have tried below but not getting any results.

```
 print doc.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/content::text()')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute axis using `@` to fetch attribute values.

For instance:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring

xml = """<some>
<nodes>
<meta itemprop="price" content="4999.00"></meta>
</nodes>
</some>"""

doc = fromstring(xml)
print(doc.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content'))
```